# MATLAB C/C++ code generation error

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I'm trying to build my simple Stateflow/Simulink design into C/C++, but I get this error. I used code generation before, but I don't know for this design it shows errors. Does anybody know what is wrong? And [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/22040/OLSS.zip), is my model.

[image]

Comment: Maybe unrelated but see http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83958-crl-simulation-target-ipp-blas-cannot-be-found-in-the-registry. Possibly some file (*.dll) required generating code got quarantined by your anti-virus? CRL stands for Code Replacement Library, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/rtwin/ref/code-generation-pane-real-time-windows-target.html.

Comment: I don't think so because I can generate code from some other models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Model toolbar select `Simulation->Model configuration parameters`. You have not setted the Code replacement library (CRL) in the `Code Generation->Interface` pane. Set it to C89/C90, C99, etc.

PS: If you want to use the code generation you must set a Fixed-step solver (with its Step time) in the `Solver` pane.